# API Post call not working from ASP.NET core app

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, post, azure-web-app-service

I have the following code in the Program class of my ASP.NET core app (hosted on Azure) POST to the Dialogflow API, however, I am apparently not receiving any data. Is there an error in my code?

```
namespace WebApplicationTest
    {
public class Program
{ 
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        makeRequest();
    }

    public static async void makeRequest()

    {
        string myJson = "{'queryInput': {'text': {'text': 'sample user query', ' languageCode': 'en-US'}}}";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsync(
                "https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/{session=projects/projectname/agent/sessions/sessionID1}:detectIntent",
                 new StringContent(myJson, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
        }
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
    }
```

Comment: what response do you get instead? Some error? Timeout? Exception thrown by your code? Other message? You need to debug a bit more. e.g. Have you set breakpoints to step through your code and see what happens at each stage, and inspect your variables?

Comment: I can't seem to do much debugging because I am not receiving a response at all

Comment: You can debug to see that the query gets executed though...like I said, step through your code...

Comment: Small typo in code: ' languageCode' => 'languageCode'

Answer (score 0):

No clue what you are trying to solve here but your `makeRequest()` won't get called since you invoke it after `BuildWebHost(args).Run()` which blocks the calling thread until host shutdown.

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostextensions.run?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_WebHostExtensions_Run_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IWebHost_).

Comment: Oh that's would make sense, where would you suggest I call the function?

Comment: As I wrote, I have no clue what you try to do there. Your namespace looks like a test, then you start a WebHost to serve any API I guess? And at the same time you want to invoke a external API with a method called makeRequest. Also it is async void which you should never do (except in very raw situtations). I would suggest to read some books about software developmet first

Comment: I am trying to call the external api via my function  when the Web page has loaded. The Web host was already in the class as the app is hosted on azure.

Comment: Then you probably want to move this to your startup.cs but please replace the void with Task and use await when you call it.